# Call web service from console application c#

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

I want to call a salesforce web service, but I get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll and Additional information: Error en el servidor remoto: (500) Error interno del servidor.

but when I call the same web service in Java I don't get any error.

This is the C# code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static String ST = "some_string";
        static String pwd = "password";
        static String userName = "myusername";
        static String SERVER_URL;
        static String SESSION_ID;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = " https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0";
            string details = CallRestMethod(url);
        }

        public static string CallRestMethod(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
            webrequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

            String input = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><Header/><Body><login xmlns=\"urn:partner.soap.sforce.com\"><username>" + userName + "</username><password>" + pwd + ST + "</password></login></Body></Envelope>";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(input);

            webrequest.GetRequestStream().Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

            /*Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
            newStream.Close();*/

            Console.WriteLine(webrequest.Headers);

            HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            string result = string.Empty;
            result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            webresponse.Close();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I can connect to the web service I added this line:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

this line is used to use the protocol TLS 1.2

Comment: Angello... you are life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a WSDL and creating a Service Reference rather than building out the request by hand.

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc636424(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: I don't want to use the wsdl, because I want to consume a custom rest method.

Comment: Then you will need to provide more details of the REST method.  Is it expecting a SOAP envelope XML as input?  Are you able to call the method with a rest client?

Comment: I want to login with the soap method and consume a rest method to insert data, I can make it with java but when I try with c# I get the error I think is the https protocol.